# Blue links in email signature on reply/forward in iOS mail

Tags: ios, email, gmail

Some of our email signature links become blue when forwarded from Gmail and viewed on iOS 10.2 Mail app. Interestingly only the second phone number and website is blue, the first number and email are not. I don't know which botches things up, Gmail or iOS mail.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            color: #0d0d0d;
            font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            margin: 8px;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100% !important;
        }

        a {
            color: #818181 !important;
            font-size: 11px !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }

        a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
            color: inherit !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            font-size: inherit !important;
            font-family: inherit !important;
            font-weight: inherit !important;
            line-height: inherit !important;
        }

        a span {
            color: #818181 !important;
            font-size: 11px !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }

        img {
            -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
            outline: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            vertical-align: baseline;
        }

        a img {
            border:none;
        }

        table td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
        }
    </style>

    <!--[if mso]>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, table, td {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
        }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body style="color: #0d0d0d;font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 11px;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;margin: 8px;padding: 0;width: 100% !important;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background-color: #ffffff;border-collapse: collapse;margin: 0;padding: 0;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom: 10px;border-collapse: collapse;">
            <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Logo" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;outline: none;text-decoration: none;vertical-align: baseline;">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom: 15px;border-collapse: collapse;">
            <span style="color: #0d0d0d; font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700;">Jane Doe</span><br>
            <span style="color: #0d0d0d; font-size: 13px;">Project Manager</span><br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom: 5px;border-collapse: collapse;">
            <img src="icon-mobile.png" alt="Mobile" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;outline: none;text-decoration: none;vertical-align: baseline;">&nbsp;<a href="tel:+400720000111" style="color: #818181 !important;font-size: 11px !important;text-decoration: none !important;"><span style="color: #818181 !important;font-size: 11px !important;text-decoration: none !important;">+400720000111</span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="icon-phone.png" alt="Phone" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;outline: none;text-decoration: none;vertical-align: baseline;">&nbsp;<a href="tel:+400720000111" style="color: #818181 !important;font-size: 11px !important;text-decoration: none !important;"><span style="color: #818181 !important;font-size: 11px !important;text-decoration: none !important;">+400720000111</span></a><br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom: 8px;border-collapse: collapse;">
            <img src="icon-mail.png" alt="Email" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;outline: none;text-decoration: none;vertical-align: baseline;">&nbsp;<a href="mailto:jdoe@gmail.com" style="color: #818181 !important;font-size: 11px !important;text-decoration: none !important;"><span style="color: #818181 !important;font-size: 11px !important;text-decoration: none !important;">jdoe@gmail.com</span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="icon-web.png" alt="Website" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;outline: none;text-decoration: none;vertical-align: baseline;">&nbsp;<a href="http://www.google.com" style="color: #818181 !important;font-size: 11px !important;text-decoration: none !important;"><span style="color: #818181 !important;font-size: 11px !important;text-decoration: none !important;">www.google.com</span></a><br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom: 2px;border-collapse: collapse;">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" style="color: #818181;font-size: 11px;text-decoration: none;"><img src="icon-fb.png" alt="Facebook" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;outline: none;text-decoration: none;vertical-align: baseline;border: none;"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" style="color: #818181;font-size: 11px;text-decoration: none;"><img src="icon-linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIN" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;outline: none;text-decoration: none;vertical-align: baseline;border: none;"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://is.gd" style="color: #818181;font-size: 11px;text-decoration: none;"><img src="icon-skype.png" alt="Skype" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;outline: none;text-decoration: none;vertical-align: baseline;border: none;"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom: 2px;border-collapse: collapse;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="305" style="border-collapse: collapse;margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 305px;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                        <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #666666;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Tried !important, doubling up the style with a span, even a[x-apple-data-detectors], but nothing seems to work.

So to recap:

- Html signature is copied into Gmail
- Email is sent, signature is fine
- Email is forwarded from Gmail and viewed on iOS Mail, signature links
  are blue
- Only 2 of the 4 links are blue!

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Have you tried to look at the same page in Safari(mobile one ofc)?

Comment: @NSDmitry it looks good in iOS Safari, viewing on gmail.com if that's what you ask

Comment: What I mean, can you create the same page and open it in Safari? To see if the problem reproduces or not. If it is - debugging mobile safari is pretty easy. Gmail could do some tricks for iOS, while your own page 100% won't.

Comment: Hi Peter, have you found a solution for this issue already? I'm facing the same problem